# pgfplotstable: How to get header-elements?

Tags: pgfplotstable

How can I replace e.g. the 'zeros' by the cell content of the current header?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
A   B
1   2
0   2
1   0
0   2
0   2
1   0
}\test

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
%string replace={0}{aaa}
]{\test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can get the header elements by transposing your table, then using `\pgfplotstablegetelem` and `\pgfplotsretval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible:

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1} {%
\pgfplotstableset{
columns/#1/.style = {
string replace={0}{\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]#1}\of\test \pgfplotsretval}
}}}%
```

But this is not so nice, because I have to say `\of\test`, so this does not work as a general style...

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
A   B
1   2
0   2
1   0
0   2
0   2
1   0
}\test

\begin{document}

% Nullen ersetzen
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1} {%
\pgfplotstableset{
columns/#1/.style = {
string replace={0}{\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]#1}\of\test \pgfplotsretval}
}}}%

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
skip rows between index={0}{1},% Benennungszeile ausblenden
every head row/.style={output empty row},% keinen header anzeigen
]{\test}

%Test:  \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\test \pgfplotsretval
%\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]1}\of\test \pgfplotsretval
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion using `expl3`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread{
A   B
1   2
0   2
1   0
0   2
0   2
1   0
}\test
\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\test}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\colmax{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnnn
  {0}{1}{\colmax}
  {
    \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{#1}\of\test\to\colname
    \pgfplotstablemodifyeachcolumnelement{\colname}\of\test\as\cell
      {\pgfmathparse{\cell==0?"\colname":\cell}\xdef\cell{\pgfmathresult}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\test}
\end{document}
```

[image]